# How to get Application file name with POCO as in GetModuleFileName (Win32 API )

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

i try to find out way to get exe file name of the application using cross platform POCO c++ lib .

tryed with :

```
char* FileName ;
FileName =  const_cast<char*>(Application::name());
```

but all i get in the FileName char * is "Application" 
what do i do wrong here ?

Comment: Doesn't `argv[0]` from the `main()` parameters work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.Application.html) says:

> application.name: the file name of the application executable

**And** there's a `name()` method:

https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Util/src/Application.cpp#L179 :

```
const char* Application::name() const
{
    return "Application";
}
```

Which I find a bit confusing. However, the docs are right:

The right way to deal with this is getting the config (`Application::config()`) and retrieving the data from therein.

Still, πάντα ῥεῖ's comment on your original question is right: No need to use a "portable" library for something that comes with the language. The `main` function's `argv[0]` is defined to contain the executable name.

Comment: Use ```Application::config().getString("application.name", "")```